# Calling method of child class from object of parent class in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, methods, polymorphism, subclass

I have a dynamic list of `Item` objects that is initialized as follows:

```
Item * items = new Item[size];
```

where `size` is an integer previously initialzed.

I populate this list with `Book` objects, where **`Book` is a child of `Item`**. Both `Book` and `Item` classes have the method `print`, which outputs a certain array of information to the console. I want to be able to call `items[x].print()` in order to call the `print` method in `Book`, which looks like this:

```
void print() {
    Item::print(); //call to print method of parent class
    <printing out some information>
}
```

Basically, I want to call the `print` method of the subclass `Book`, which in turn calls the `print` method of `Item`, which prints out more general information. However, using `items[x].print()` only calls the `print` method in `Item`. How do I call the `print` method of the `Book` class in the array `items` of type `Item`?

Comment: Q; So you've having Book::print() call Item::print()?  And then you also want Item::print() to call Book::print()?  Q: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: It only calls the print method in Item, not Book.

Comment: No, but I've tried virtual and I get the same result.

Comment: If the base class is Item and the child class's method Book::print() needs to call Item::print, then the syntax ` Item::print()` is perfectly appropriate.  If you declare an array of "Item", but store a "Book" object ... then you should cast the object before you it's "print".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use

```
Item * items = new Item[size];
```

Each element of the array `items` is an `Item` object. Even if `print()` were a virtual function, `Book::print()` will never be called if you use:

```
items[x].print();
```

In order to be able to call `Book::print()`, you need to store pointers, not objects.

```
Item** items = new Item*[size];
```

Then, you can use:

```
items[x]->print();
```

as long as you fill up the array with properly defined pointers.

Example:

```
Item** items = new Item*[5];
items[0] = new Book;
items[0]->print();
```